# DataStax Solr index rebuild. reload all data from cassandra table

Tags: indexing, solr, cql, datastax, rebuild

I created a table using cql, inserted 2 rows to that table and created solr index using datastax procedures. The index has no documents.
If I inserted another row to the table using cql, The index has 1 document not 3 documents.

I tried to delete the index data and rebuild the index using dsetool rebuildindexes command
dsetool -h localhost rebuild_indexes demo_db tbl_1 demo_db.tbl_1

but the index still has 1 documents instead of 3 documents.

Is there any way to rebuild the index to be loaded with all rows in the table?

Comment: I'll assume you're on DSE 4.6.x. In that case, you might want to look at dsetool reload_core. See http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/tools/toolsDsetool.html?scroll=refDseJTMgmt__reload_core

Comment: I tried the same scenario again in new table but this problem didn't appear. I created a test table, inserted some records, and then created the index. I found the pre-inserted records exist in the index :)